# R reconstruct data

Tags: r, reshape

I want to reshape my data but couldn't figure out how because it's not exactly from wide to long.

Here's a sample of my data, population by single year of age and by sex

```
data <- structure(list(`2010 - Both Sexes - 0` = 163753, `2010 - Male - 0` = 83878, `2010 - Female - 0` = 79875, `2011 - Both Sexes - 0` = 161923, 
                       `2011 - Male - 0` = 83134, `2011 - Female - 0` = 78789, `2010 - Both Sexes - 1` = 163043, 
                       `2010 - Male - 1` = 83174, `2010 - Female - 1` = 79869, `2011 - Both Sexes - 1` = 163342, 
                       `2011 - Male - 1` = 83472, `2011 - Female - 1` = 79870), row.names = c(NA, 
                         -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My desired dataset would look like the following:

```
 age  2010 - Both Sexes   2010 - Male   2010 - Female  2011 - Both Sexes 2011 - Male   2011 - Female ...
  0                                     
  1

                 ...
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: 1. Where does `age` come from? Not all columns have `- 0` or `- 1`. 2. That's looks like an awful (untidy) output format. Is that really want you want?

Comment: @MauritsEvers `age` would be a new column, columns that don't have 0 or 1 are the total population. I just deleted them.

Comment: I would really urge you to reconsider the format. This is the opposite of tidy. That aside, you've got a solution below.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks for your suggestions. Guess we're having different definitions of tidiness. The data I want to obtain is how the data are originally presented on Census's website, when I download the data, I got this extremely wide data.

Comment: Fair enough. BTW, the definition of "tidy data" is pretty unambiguous and defined in [Tidy Data by Hadley Wickham, Journal of Statistical Software 59 (2014)](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf).

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks for sharing this. Good to know that someone has defined it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would ever want this format, but you can do it with `tidyr` like so:

1. `gather` all the columns into colnames and populations;
2. `separate` out the `age` from the other two by splitting on the second `-`;
3. `spread` back out the population values.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- structure(list(`2010 - Both Sexes - 0` = 163753, `2010 - Male - 0` = 83878, `2010 - Female - 0` = 79875, `2011 - Both Sexes - 0` = 161923, `2011 - Male - 0` = 83134, `2011 - Female - 0` = 78789, `2010 - Both Sexes - 1` = 163043, `2010 - Male - 1` = 83174, `2010 - Female - 1` = 79869, `2011 - Both Sexes - 1` = 163342, `2011 - Male - 1` = 83472, `2011 - Female - 1` = 79870), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data %>%
  gather(year_sex_age, population) %>%
  separate(year_sex_age, c("year_sex", "age"), sep = " - (?=0|1)") %>%
  spread(year_sex, population)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>   age   `2010 - Both Se~ `2010 - Female` `2010 - Male` `2011 - Both Se~
#>   <chr>            <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 0               163753           79875         83878           161923
#> 2 1               163043           79869         83174           163342
#> # ... with 2 more variables: `2011 - Female` <dbl>, `2011 - Male` <dbl>
```

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).